# WSO2 - Server's certificate is not trusted

Tags: ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, wso2

I'm setting up my development environment using the binary files that I have downloaded from WSO2's website.

I'm getting an issue related to the SSL certificate which prevents me to call some URI's from my Ruby script. How can I can fix this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing the SSL Certificate into the client-truststore in repository/resources/security?

Comment: Yes, I tried. I have solved this issue adding the certificate into Mac Os's trusted list.